# Python upgrade from 2.7 to 3.7 : unicode error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

I am updating my python code from 2.7 to 3.7.
Basically, I am trying to run a pipeline on google dataflow which reads the data from Big Query view and transforms it and then writes back to big query in another table.

However, while updating if I am using unicode error : **NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined**

```
            bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)
            records = (pipeline
                      | 'Read %s From BQ' % v.get('name') >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
                      | 'BQ Create KV %s' % count >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['value'].encode("utf-8"),
                                                                            {unicode(key).encode("utf-8"): unicode(
                                                                                value).encode("utf-8")
                                                                            for key, value in row.items()}))
                      | 'BQ Group By Key %s' % count >> beam.GroupByKey()
                      | 'BQ Calculate %s  Score' % v.get('name') >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDataDoFn(),
                                                                                    filter_id=v.get('filter_id'),
                                                                                    date=date)
                      )
```

If I am running the same code as above in python 2.7 it runs fine.

After sometime I tried to update the code as I read unicode in python 3+ as str - if I updated my code to replace unicode as str. The files from big query are not being read hence resulting in Key Error Later :

```
            bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)
            records = (pipeline
                      | 'Read %s From BQ' % v.get('name') >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
                      | 'BQ Create KV %s' % count >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['value'].encode("utf-8"),
                                                                            {str(key).encode("utf-8"): str(
                                                                                value).encode("utf-8")
                                                                            for key, value in row.items()}))
                      | 'BQ Group By Key %s' % count >> beam.GroupByKey()
                      | 'BQ Calculate %s Score' % v.get('name') >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDataDoFn(),
```

EDIT 1 :

Update code without encoding - Works now.

```
bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)
                records = (pipeline
                           | 'Read %s From BQ' % v.get('name') >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
                           | 'BQ Create KV %s' % count >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['value'],
                                                                                {key:
                                                                                     value
                                                                                 for key, value in row.items()}))
                           | 'BQ Group By Key %s' % count >> beam.GroupByKey()
                           | 'BQ Calculate %s  Score' % v.get('name') >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDataDoFn(),
                                                                                         filter_id=v.get('filter_id'),
                                                                                         date=date)
                           )
```

Comment: What is the type of the keys _before_ you call `str` on them?

Comment: its int type @snakecharmerb

Comment: have you tried not encoding? In python3 that forces it to bytes, whereas in python2 it just makes it str. I'd post a more detailed answer, but I don't have google big query to test on.

Comment: Yeah - It works now.

Comment: Put your update as your own answer so you can mark this as resolved.

Comment: I can post my answer, now that it's tested and confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = 'hello'
u = u'hello'
b = u.encode('utf-8')
print (type(s), type(u), type(b))
```

in python38

> <class 'str'> <class 'str'> <class 'bytes'>

in python27

> (<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'>)

The intent of that conversion is clearly to convert unicode to str, which is no longer a relevant concern in python3. Instead we're changing it to bytes, which is not compatible. Simply do not encode, and use str(key) -- or just key, if you already know it's unicode.